# Initial value of Cascading DropDown List

Tags: asp.net-mvc

My code works fine but after selecting any Country when I go and select the default value that is select country then the state drop down is not cleared it still shows the old value.

Controller :

```
 public ActionResult Countries()
    {
        List<Countries> objCountries = new List<Countries>();
        objCountries.Add(new Countries { CountryId = 1, CountryName = "India" });
        objCountries.Add(new Countries { CountryId = 2, CountryName = "Japan" });
        objCountries.Add(new Countries { CountryId = 3, CountryName = "France" });
        ViewBag.counties = new SelectList(objCountries, "CountryId", "CountryName");
        return View();

    }

    public JsonResult States(int id)
    {
        List<States> objstates = new List<Models.States>();
        objstates.Add(new States { CountryId = 1, StateName = "Hyderabad" });
        objstates.Add(new States { CountryId = 1, StateName = "Chennai" });
        objstates.Add(new States { CountryId = 2, StateName = "JapanState1" });
        objstates.Add(new States { CountryId = 2, StateName = "JapanState2" });
        objstates.Add(new States { CountryId = 3, StateName = "FranceState1" });
        objstates.Add(new States { CountryId = 3, StateName = "FranceState2" });
        var state = from s in objstates where s.CountryId == id select s;
        return Json(new SelectList(state.ToArray(), "CountryId", "StateName"),
            JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    }
```

View :

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.7.1.min.js"></script>
 <script>
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#counties").change(function () {
        $.getJSON('/Cascading/States/' + $("#counties").val(), function (data) {
            var items = '<option>Select a State</option>';
            $.each(data, function (i, state) {
                items += "<option value='" + state.Value + "'>" + state.Text + "</option>";
            });
            $("#States").html(items);
        });

    });
});
```

```
<h2>Countries</h2>

 @Html.DropDownList("counties", "select Country")

<select id="States"></select>
```

Answer (score 0):

This code should work:

```
$('#countries').change(function () {
                jQuery.getJSON('/Cascading/States/', { id: $(this).val() }, function (data) {
                    $('#States').empty();
                    jQuery.each(data, function (i) {
                        var option = $('<option></option>').attr("value", data[i].data[i].Value).text(data[i].Text);
                        $("#States").append(option);
                    });
                });
});
```

Comment: Its not working, the state drop down is not populating.